# If statement for taxonomies?

Tags: hugo

I have a switch and want to add an `if` statement for taxonomies but don't know how to call it? I tried if `.IsTaxonomy` but get an error...

```
{{ if eq .Type "blog" }}
  {{ .Title }}
{{ end }}

{{ if eq .Type "help" }}
  {{ .Title }}
{{ end }}

{{ if eq .Type "reviews" }}
  {{ .Title }}
{{ end }}

{{ if .IsHome }}
  home
{{ else if eq .Type "page" }}
  {{ .Title }}
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a switch and want to add an if statement for taxonomies but don't know how to call it? I tried if .IsTaxonomy but get an error...

The `.Type` variable that you use with your if statements is something that Hugo gets from the content folder (more precisely the section). So your posts stored in `/content/tutorial/` get the `tutorial` type. You can also set the type of a piece of content by hand. But `.Type` does not by default equal the content's taxonomy.

An alternative is to use Hugo's `.IsNode` [page variable](https://gohugo.io/variables/page/) -- that one always returns `true` when the current page is a list page. That is, a page with posts from a certain taxonomy or section.

You can inspect the page's `.RelPermalink` variable to see if the current page contains some taxonomy name (like `"reviews"`). But I would advise against that, since it isn't a good practice. Any taxonomy change you make or new taxonomy means your theme's code need to be changed. Plus it also requires that you (or your users) never make a spelling mistake with taxonomy names, since else the theme's code breaks.

If I look at your if statements code, the following seems to be the equivalent of what you're trying to do:

```
{{ if .IsNode }} 

    <!-- Taxonomy and section list pages -->
    {{ .Title }}

{{ else if .IsPage }} 

    <!-- Content pages -->

{{ else if .IsHome }} 

    <!-- Homepage -->
    home

{{ else }}

    <!-- All other pages, like the 404 page -->

{{ end }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write a detailed explanation on Hugo's if statements, I learned a lot from this since I just started with Hugo a week ago! I wish I could upvote this more :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Have a nice day!